# Use Lambda As Argument In Function

Tags: c++, function, lambda

```
void f(int a, void(*b)(int))
{
   b(a);
}

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 6;

  f(10, [a, b](int x) { cout << a+b+x; });

  return 0;
}
```

If I won't use 'a' and 'b' variables, everything works good, otherwise, C++ returns:

error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda(int)>' to 'void (*)(int)''

note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void f(int, void (*)(int))'

Answer (score 3):

[Lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with captures can't convert to function pointer.

You can use `std::function` as parameter type instead. e.g.

```
void f(int a, std::function<void(int)> b)
{
   b(a);
}
```